# "Translation to" or "Translation into"?

Tags: prepositions, questions, translation

```
Translation from Mongolian ... English
```

In official translation, should I use "To" or "Into"

Comment: *Into* is a safer bet, but that doesn't mean that the use of *to* is unheard of.

Comment: Sure, but *translated to* usually means something else--it's usually followed not by the target language, but by the result of the translation.  (It *can* be used the other way, it's just less common.)

Comment: This question has also been answered [at ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51209/translate-into-vs-translate-to)

Answer (score 1):

> ... translated from Mongolian to English
>   ... translated from mongolian into English

I think each sounds fine.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

---

### On Usage and Style

<sub>Disclaimer: OPINION</sub>

1. > The document was translated from Mongolian **???** English.

   "To" fits well here because of the `from...to` construction.
2. Removing `from Mongolian` leaving only:

   > The document was translated **???** English.

   "Into" sounds more appropriate.
3. Removing everything else except for the languages:

   > Mongolian **???** English

   "To" retains the simplicity. It's also used by a lot of online translators and dictionary titles.

   Also, a simple hyphen "-" would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> Translation from Mongolian into English

It uses the format of...

> [*translation from something **into** something*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/translation)

It gives an example -

> *He specializes in translation from Danish into English.*