# Change the language of a website to/into English

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, idioms, phrase-choice, collocations

Let's say I am looking at a website with a friend. The website is shown in a language other than English. Can I say these two sentences interchangeably to my friend if I want him to select "English" on the menu of the site as the language of the site.

- *Change the language to English.*
- *Change the language into English.*

I think we can say the first sentence, but I am not sure of the second one. From what I read in [this answer,](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79216/im-wondering-about-the-difference-between-change-into-and-change-to)[1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79216/im-wondering-about-the-difference-between-change-into-and-change-to) I think "into" could probably be used too here because the site would still have the same entity even if the language changed. What do you think?

Comment: Websites have or do not have translations. The translations are indicated by a drop-down menu. So the word change is wrong. Choose [language] from the menu. In any case, you can't change one language into another. You can, however, change  frog into a prince if you are a witch.

Comment: 'Switch the language to English' might work better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Translation to" or "Translation into"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20440/translation-to-or-translation-into) See also [What does "into" here mean? (Translate your thinking into English.)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/178832/what-does-into-here-mean-translate-your-thinking-into-english) Short answer: both prepositions are fine, and mean the same.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The translations are already done. The choice of language is in the menu. "I want him to select "English" on the menu of the site as the language of the site".

Comment: Nobody would really care about the "syntax" of any such label, because no normal website would feature "sentences" for the relevant hotspot controls. All you need is the name of each language (in it's own language, so you might have one button marked ***English*** and another labelled ***Francais***; it would be a bit silly to have one labelled ***German*** that an actual German might not even understand! :)

Comment: You change the **language** of the website to English. That translates the **website** into English, or displays the English version of the website.

Comment: In Kazakhstan, websites typically do not even use the complete spelling of the languages in their menus. This is quite common: **ENG ҚАЗ РУС**. No one is ever confused.